# Ad-hoc notifications not working but no errors

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

Notifications are working correctly with my Development Provisioning Profile but when I use a Distribution Provisioning Profile for Ad-hoc testing the app stops receiving notifications.

1. Registration to the notification server is fine as the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is invoked correctly;
2. The entitlements in the Distribution Provisioning Profile correctly show "production" for the "aps-environment" key;
3. The server side connects to the "gateway.push.apple.com" on port 2195;
4. The server sends the notification to the Apple Gateway using the token received from their APNS server with no errors;
5. The Ad-hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile uses the right AppID which is enabled for both Development and Production push-notifications;
6. The Ad-hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile is also based on the right Production Certificate.

I'm lost and don't have any more ideas about what to check...